# Installer custom Actions

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

How to Delete all the Folders Created by the Application in the Application Start Up Path (Program Files) at the Unistall.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful also with deleting folders. What if some user just installs your program into C:. Do you clean up his whole drive afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to, the uninstall will keep a log at install and do this for you.

However I guess you're pointing out that it won't delete things that it didn't install in the first place.  On that basis you should override the [rollback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.rollback.aspx)/[uninstall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.uninstall.aspx) methods on your custom [Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.aspx) class and write code that looks for and removes stuff that was created since the install (possibly by your application).

Be aware though that even with this approach, you might find it tough to make sure the folder (with the uninstall log) is removed totally.